# Obi-Wan's path from Docking Bay 327 to the tractor beam

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

Can anyone give me a diagram of the path that Obi-w-Wan Kenobi took from the docking bay to where he shut down the tractor beam on the Death Star? For a party game, I'll be laying out a big circle on the floor and kids need to find the way from the beginning to the end - kind of like a life-size maze!

Comment: Not an answer, but I suspect you'd find this interesting; https://spalanz.com/2015/04/07/escape-from-the-death-star/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming he took the most direct route (sticking to the exterior corridors) and avails himself of the convenient turboshaft lifts and travel tubes, his route would be relatively straightforward.

Note that this is a 2D representation of an approximately 100km round trip around the outside of the station, roughly the distance from London to Southampton.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Star Wars: Blueprints - The Ultimate Collection**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ultimate-Blueprints-Collection-Double-Sided-Poster-Sized/dp/0756638690)</sup></sub>

Comment: Knowing this information will make my commute from Southampton to London much more bearable.

Comment: @Alistair86 - Alas, nothing I say can make it any more bearable to live in Southampton.

Comment: #sigh# so true..

Comment: wow, 100km DOES seem an awful lot....couldn't there be some lifts/moving platforms to speed that trip? surely a station of that size cannot function without some fast transportation method...

Comment: @Sebustyan - Worth asking as a new question